# UITableviewController losing reference to tableview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, reference

I have been working on this for 2 days now, cant seem to get a grasp. I'm missing something very basic I guess.

Here's what I have:

A UIViewController as the Apps root controller.
There's a ContainerView, a subclass of UIView which I add to my root controller view.
Within that I want a UITableView.

Since there are several different Containers, I have different Nibs for each.

Heres how its wired: Nib with content, has the container as its file's owner. There's an outlet to the UITableView, it has the container as source and delegate.

The container implements the protocol methods.

Now I can't call reloaddata on the UITableView since it's nil. I type po in the consolo and it says 0x0 but I don't know why.

I have been trying different approaches, but all ended up in losing the reference to the tableView.

It's not like it's my first tableview I create but I have no clue on what I'm doing wrong here.

Any HELP please!!!!

Code:

This is my Outlet:

```
IBOutlet UITableView *contactsTV;
```

File's owner has a connection to it, the tableview vice versa.

I create the nib by doing:

```
    Contentview *v = [[Contentview alloc] initWithFrame:[[contentViewArray objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue]];
```

while contentViewArray is some array storing Framevalues as strings.
Then I do:

```
[v prepareView];
```

and it looks like this:

```
- (void) prepareView {

NSArray *mediaPlayerViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" 
                                                          owner:self 
                                                        options:nil];

UIView *v = (UIView *)[mediaPlayerViews objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubview:v];
}
```

Comment: If you post some code, it would be a lot easier to find the problem. Maybe you aren't connecting the tableview to the right object in the nib?

Comment: Added some code - hope it helps.

Comment: When you say [self addSubview:v], is the "self" here a UIView, or a UIViewController?

Answer (score 2):

Just experienced a similar issue -- everything appeared wired up correctly (Xcode 4) but the outlet reference was nil.

When I created the file, I used the "New File" -> subclass of UITableViewController. with NIB (automatic) process to set up the file.  This resulted in the controller being declared as a UITableViewController and the NIB had a UITableView as it's root.

Although the TableDataSource and TableDelegate methods got called as expected, the outlet for the TableView was never being set when the nib was loaded.

To fix this, I basically had to change the controller from being a subclass of UITableViewController to just UIViewController and set the NIB accordingly:  I cleared the NIB, added a UIView with a UITableView as a child, reconnected the outlets (View, TableView, TableDataSource, and TableDelegate), and it all worked as planned.

I think this may be a bug with XCode, when creating a subclass of UITableView with NIB.

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a `UITableViewController` it should work.

Comment: Do I have to do this? I thought mine was a proper way to handle it. Besides, I had this as as UITableViewController and it didnt work - same problem, lost the reference..... :/

Comment: Try NSLogging at various points and check the values in the array and try to display `self.tableView`

Comment: i was adding the tableview before like this - self.tableview - ..... it appeared properly, reacted also, but i couldnt reach it any more, once everything was set up....

Comment: Did you allocate your tableview ?

Comment: its wired up in IB. when calling my prepareView Method, the table exists, i.e. is not nil, so i did not see the need to allocate it again. or do i?

Comment: i do not have a viewdidload method. i create the view programmatically and then call loadnibnamed to get the wiring from nib to my contentview. if i check for the tableview in my prepareview method, it existsm but later on, not any more....

Comment: What does it display when you do `NSLog ("%@", self.tableView);`

Comment: <UITableView: 0x83d600; frame = (0 0; 840 504); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x181150>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is the output...

Comment: Good. Try doing in various stages of the program and most importantly, before `reloadData` and let me know

Comment: same there, <UITableView: 0x83cc00; frame = (0 0; 840 504); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x180920>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: Then your tableView is not null, its not hooked up properly.

Comment: wicked :) but actually, i cant see how. I've done this a hundred times. Lets say, I know how to hook em up. And I did it correctly. :) Any idea on what I might b missing else? I suppose its because of the loadnibnamed stuff..

Comment: Yeah. This always happens when you depend too much on the interface builder. Try programming individual views, setting frames and so on - it's actually much easier to learn concepts and much easier to debug. With IB, you just do not know where the problem was.

Comment: i guess. will have to redo it up manually then. thanks anyways for your time n patience!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have property set in header file along with

```
IBOutlet UITableView *contactsTV
```

?

If you don't have setter method for your contactsTV, then your contactsTV isn't retained by your object.

Try to replace your code with

```
//header file
UITableView *contactsTV;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *contactsTV;

//implementation file
@synthesize contactsTV;
```

Comment: property is set/was set properly before.